# Unity AR Integration into Swift 4

Tags: swift, xcode, unity-game-engine, swift4

I try to integrate a unity project ( using Unity 2018.2.4f1 - latest one at the moment ) into xCode ( version 9.4.1 - latest stable version at the moment ) and I encounter so so many errors in the last few days but I fixed all of them. Now I have this errors which I really don't know hot to fix them. I researched a lot and nobody have a right answer regarding this errors:

> "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ARWorldTrackingConfiguration", referenced from:
>   objc-class-ref in ARSessionNative.o
>
> "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AROrientationTrackingConfiguration", referenced from:
>   objc-class-ref in ARSessionNative.o
>
> "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ARAnchor", referenced from: referenced from:
>   objc-class-ref in ARSessionNative.o
>
> "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ARPlaneAnchor", referenced from: objc-class-ref in
>   ARSessionNative.o
>
> "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ARSession", referenced from: objc-class-ref in
>   ARSessionNative.o

Is any chance that any of you to encounter this errors and to know a solution to fix them ?
My Library Search Path is set correctly if you are wondering about this: $(inherited) $(PROJECT_DIR)/NameOfMyProject/Unity/Libraries

Also I delete everything from Derived Data and I clean the project and rebuild so many times. I tried different versions of Unity to export the project and also I tried different versions of xCode to integrate the Unity project, none of them helped me.

Here is a screenshot with the errors:
[image: Unity ARKit Plugin Errors]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this errors after a long research.
The fix was to include the ARKit Framework into the xCode Project.

[image: Added ARKit Library]